# Larverl's response()->file() must be prefixed with the current directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

On a fresh Laravel 8 installation I follow these steps:

1. php artisan storage:link
2. Inside `/public/storage/` I create folder `images/` and inside I paste an image called `picture.png`
3. In web.php I define a route like this:

   ```
   Route::get('/picture', function(
      return response()->file(Storage::url("images/picture.png")); 
   ))
   ```

However, if I visit this route in browser, the picture is not shown and the following error is thrown:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException
The file "/storage/images/picture.png" does not exist
```

**It works only if** the url inside `response()->file()` is prefixed with `./` indicating the current directory like this:

```
return response()->file('./'.Storage::url("images/picture.png"));
```

I don't think it is a good idea to work with relative paths locally, the Storage and file methods should handle this. Maybe it is even an issue with the framework.

Any ideas how to go around this hack?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't configure the local driver check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk and look for local driver.
If you configure it right it should return the "/" that you're adding manually.